# How to package my android app with a database

Tags: android, installation, sqlite

I've already created an android application that has got an already existing sqlite 3 database within it's asset's folder. I designed the application to copy the database on to the mobile when the app is launched for the first time. My question is how can I ship the database and the app so that users can easily install the app?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The method I'm going to show you takes
>   your own SQLite database file from the
>   "assets" folder and copies into the
>   system database path of your
>   application so the SQLiteDatabase API
>   can open and access it normally.

Have a look here : [Using your own sqlite database in your Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)